# Windows service running in a Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, anaconda

I need to run a Flask application as a Windows service. I managed to convert it to a Windows service using win32serviceutil. The problem I have is that it only works when I manually run PythonService.exe (with the -debug flag) from the "activated" environment (of course).

Is there a way to activate the environment before attempting to run the service?

I see some people used the Task Scheduler as a workaround but I'd prefer if Windows service manager could be used instead.

Comment: I'm really confused. Anaconda is a utility that runs on Fedora, which has nothing to do with Windows services. Are you trying to get a Python Flask application to run on Windows as a Window service? If so, where does Anaconda fit in? Or are you trying to get a Windows Service to run in Linux?

Comment: Anaconda, Inc. is a company that makes a Python binary distribution for Windows.

Comment: Sorry. No idea about anaconda. You might want to check the account that the service runs under. It needs to have whatever permissions your app has. Also, services have no desktop session. I'm not sure if your app expects one or not.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The trick is to use pyinstaller to generate an EXE. This way all libraries will be included, and there will be no need to mess with the system environment variables.